# Exporting .blend file to .skp?

Tags: export, file-format

I have question. Im using blender 3.3.0 and i would need to export my .blend format to .skp(sketchup) format. Is this possible or how would i be able to do this?

Comment: As far as I know you can import _Collada (.dae)_ files into Sketchup. Maybe try this, there is an exporter for _Collada_ in Blender. I just read somewhere you might have to check "Selection Only" on export (and of course have the object selected you want to export). But I'd rather not give this as an answer since I have no Sketchup to validate this method.